# Issue with timer in .lsl (Linden Scripting Language)

Tags: linden-scripting-language

Have a problem with the script below written in .lsl (Linden Scripting Language)

It is designed to let one renter A (first renter) to rent the space and can rent out the space for renter B (second renter)

The 1st problem is that for renter B the time the space is rented for ends to fast. Applys from state active

And 2nd problem is renter B should pay at least 25% of the total price renter A sets at the first time, but after the init price is payed renter B cannot pay any more even the total amount payed should be what renter A sets.

```
//varibles for renter A
//    elapsedRentalTime = .0;
//    rentalTime = 0;
//    rentalName = "<No body>";
//    rentalUUID = NULL_KEY;
//    rentalSetPrice = 0;
//    rentalSetTime = .0;

//varibles for renter B
//    endName = "<No Body>";
//    endUUID = NULL_KEY;
//    endRentalTime = .0;
//    endRentalPayd = 0;
```

Hope somone can help with this issue. also sorry for any typeos there may be : )

```
//cant pay after the int 25% of amt / renter time for renter B ends to fast

integer chan;
list butPrice = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","Set price","Reset price"];
list butTime = ["Hour+","Hour-","Day+","Day-","Week+","Week-","Set time","Reset time"];
integer lis1;
key owner;
integer rentPrice;
float rentTime;
float dialogTime = .0;

key rentalUUID = NULL_KEY;
string rentalName = "<No body>";
float rentalTime;
float elapsedRentalTime;
integer rentalSetPrice;
float rentalSetTime;

key endUUID = NULL_KEY;
string endName = "<No body>";
float endRentalTime;
integer endRentalPayd;

float ONE_WEEK = 604800.0;
float ONE_DAY  = 86400.0;
float ONE_HOUR = 3600.0;
string getTimeString(integer time){
    string str;

    integer week;
    integer days;
    integer hours;
    integer minutes; 
    integer seconds;

    week = llRound(time / 604800);
    time = time % 604800;

    days = (time / 86400);
    time = time % 86400;

    hours = (time / 3600);
    time  = time % 3600;

    minutes = time / 60;
    time    = time % 60;

    seconds = time;

    if(week)
        str += (string)week + " weeks, ";
    if(days)
        str += (string)days + " days, ";
    if(hours)
        str += (string)hours + " hours, ";
    if(minutes)
        str += (string)minutes + " minutes, ";
    if(seconds)
        str += (string)seconds + " seconds, ";
    if(str != "")
        str = llDeleteSubString(str,-2,-1);
    if(str == "")
        str = "Not Set!";

    return str;
}

Dialog2(key i,string str,list but){
    dialogTime += 15.;
    llListenRemove(lis1);
    lis1 = llListen(chan,"","","");
    llDialog(i,str,but,chan);
}

EndRental(){
    llSetTimerEvent(.0);
    elapsedRentalTime = .0;
    rentalTime = 0;
    rentalName = "<No body>";
    rentalUUID = NULL_KEY;
    rentalSetPrice = 0;
    rentalSetTime = .0;
    endName = "<No Body>";
    endUUID = NULL_KEY;
    endRentalTime = .0;
    endRentalPayd = 0;
    llMessageLinked(LINK_THIS, 1, "Free space|Rate L$"+(string)rentPrice+" \ week|Max: "+getTimeString((integer)rentTime), llGetKey());
}

integer subPrice;
integer Config1(key i,string m){
    if(m == "Set price"){
        Dialog2(i,"Price: "+(string)subPrice+"L$",["Ok"]);
        return subPrice;
    }
    else if(m == "Reset price")
        subPrice = 0;
    else
        subPrice = (integer)((string)subPrice+m);
    Dialog2(i,"(Set price)\n"+(string)subPrice+"L$",butPrice);
    return subPrice;
}

integer subTime;
integer Config2(key i,string m){
    if(m == "Hour+")
        subTime += 3600;
    else if(m == "Hour-")
        subTime -= 3600;
    else if(m == "Day+")
        subTime += 86400;
    else if(m == "Day-")
        subTime -= 86400;
    else if(m == "Week+")
        subTime += 604800;
    else if(m == "Week-")
        subTime -= 604800;
    else if(m == "Set time"){
        Dialog2(i,"Time: "+(string)getTimeString(subTime),["Ok"]);
        return subTime;
    }
    else if(m == "Reset time")
        subTime = 0;
    Dialog2(i,"(Set time)\n"+getTimeString((integer)subTime),butTime);
    return subTime;
}

TextInfo(){
    llWhisper(0,"Price: L$ "+(string)rentPrice+" / week\nMax time: "+getTimeString((integer)rentTime)+"\n---------------------\nRenter: "+rentalName+"\nEnd user: "+endName+
    "\n---------------------\nPrice: L$ "+(string)rentalSetPrice+"\nTime: "+getTimeString((integer)rentalSetTime));
}

DisplayInfo(){
    llMessageLinked(LINK_THIS, 1, "COST: "+(string)rentalSetPrice+"|PAID: "+(string)endRentalPayd+"|BUYER: "+endName, llGetKey());
}

default{

    touch_end(integer e){
        if(llDetectedKey(0) == owner){
            subTime = subPrice = 0;
            if(dialogTime == .0)
                llSetTimerEvent(5.);
            Dialog2(owner,"(Menu)",["Price","Time","Info","Activet"]);
        }
    }

    listen(integer c,string n,key i,string m){
        if(i == owner){
            if(m == "Info")
                TextInfo();
            else if(m == "Activet"){
                llMessageLinked(LINK_THIS, 1, "Free space|Rate L$"+(string)rentPrice+" \ week|Max: "+getTimeString((integer)rentTime), llGetKey());
                llSetTimerEvent(.0);
                state active;
            }
            else if(~llListFindList(butPrice,[m]) || m == "Price")
                rentPrice = Config1(i,m);
            else if(~llListFindList(butTime,[m]) || m == "Time")
                rentTime = (float)Config2(i,m);
        }
    }

    timer(){
        float elapsedTime = llGetTime();
        llResetTime();
        if((dialogTime -= elapsedTime) <= .0){
            dialogTime = .0;
            llListenRemove(lis1);
            llSetTimerEvent(.0);
        }
    }

    run_time_permissions(integer p){
        if(!(p & PERMISSION_DEBIT)){
            llOwnerSay("Debit perm not set! Reseting script...");
            llResetScript();
        }
    }

    state_entry(){
        owner = llGetOwner();
        llRequestPermissions(owner,PERMISSION_DEBIT);
        chan = (integer)llGetSubString("0x"+(string)llGetKey(),-1,-5);
    }

    on_rez(integer r){
        llResetScript();
    }

}

state active{

    state_entry(){
    }

    touch_end(integer e){
        key id = llDetectedKey(0);
        if(id == rentalUUID){
            Dialog2(rentalUUID,"(Renter Menu)",["Price","Time","End rental","Info"]);
        }
        else if(id == owner)
            Dialog2(owner,"(Owner menu)",["No refund","Refund","Info"]);
        else
            Dialog2(id,"(Menu)",["Info"]);
    }

    listen(integer c,string n,key i,string m){
        if(m == "Info")
            TextInfo();
        else if(i == rentalUUID){
            if(m == "End rental")
                Dialog2(rentalUUID,"(Menu)\nEnd rental with  no refun?",["No ref!","Cancel"]);
            else if(m == "No ref!")
                EndRental();
            else if(~llListFindList(butPrice,[m]) || m == "Price")
                rentalSetPrice = Config1(i,m);
            else if(~llListFindList(butTime,[m]) || m == "Time")
                rentalSetTime = (float)Config2(i,m);
            if(rentalSetTime+elapsedRentalTime > rentTime+120.){
                rentalSetTime = 0;
                llInstantMessage(rentalUUID,"Time set is greater then max rental time allowd");
            }
            DisplayInfo();
        }
        else if(i == owner){
            if(m == "No refund")
                Dialog2(owner,"(Owner menu)\nEnd rental with no refund?",["No ref!","Cancel"]);
            else if(m == "Refund")
                Dialog2(owner,"(Owner menu)\nEnd rental with refund?",["Ref!","Cancel"]);
            else if(m == "No ref!")
                EndRental();
            else if(m == "Ref!"){
                integer amt = (integer)(rentalTime * rentPrice / ONE_WEEK);
                if(amt)
                    llGiveMoney(rentalUUID,amt);
                EndRental();
            }
        }
    }

    timer(){
        float elapsedTime = llGetTime();
        llResetTime();
        rentalTime -= elapsedTime;
        elapsedRentalTime += elapsedTime;
        endRentalTime -= elapsedTime;
        dialogTime -= elapsedTime;

        if(rentalTime <= .0 && rentalUUID != NULL_KEY){
            llInstantMessage(rentalUUID,"Your rental time at "+llGetRegionName()+" has now ended.");
            EndRental();
        }
        if(endRentalTime <= .0 && endUUID != NULL_KEY){
            llInstantMessage(endUUID,"Your rental time at "+llGetRegionName()+" has now ended.");
            endName = "<No Body>";
            endUUID = NULL_KEY;
            endRentalTime = .0;
            endRentalPayd = 0;
            DisplayInfo();
        }
        if(dialogTime <= .0){
            dialogTime = .0;
            llListenRemove(lis1);
        }
    }

    money(key i,integer amt){
        float sum;
        sum = ONE_WEEK * amt / rentPrice;
        if(i == rentalUUID && sum + rentalTime + elapsedRentalTime <= rentTime){
            rentalTime += sum;
            llInstantMessage(rentalUUID,"You have refiled for "+getTimeString((integer)sum)+"\nand your total time is "+getTimeString((integer)sum));
        }
        else if(rentalUUID == NULL_KEY && sum <= rentTime){
            rentalUUID = i;
            rentalName = llKey2Name(rentalUUID);
            rentalTime = sum;
            llResetTime();
            llInstantMessage(rentalUUID,"Your time left is "+getTimeString((integer)sum));
            llSetTimerEvent(30.);
        }
        else if(i == endUUID && endRentalPayd+amt <= rentalSetPrice){
            endRentalTime += rentalSetTime * amt / rentalSetPrice;
            endRentalPayd += amt;
            llGiveMoney(rentalUUID,amt);
            llInstantMessage(endUUID,"Your time left is "+getTimeString((integer)endRentalTime));
        }
        else if(endUUID == NULL_KEY && amt >= rentalSetPrice*25/100 && amt <= rentalSetPrice && rentalUUID != NULL_KEY){
            endUUID = i;
            endName = llKey2Name(endUUID);
            endRentalTime = rentalSetTime * amt / rentalSetPrice;
            endRentalPayd = amt;
            llGiveMoney(rentalUUID,amt);
            llInstantMessage(endUUID,"Your time left is "+getTimeString((integer)endRentalTime));
        }
        else
            llGiveMoney(i,amt);
        DisplayInfo();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recode to use [LSL wiki / llGetUnixTime](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LlGetUnixTime)

this gives the code a easy to use set point in time to work from.

```
integer rental_expires = 0;
integer number_of_days_per_payment = 7;
integer secs_per_day = 86400; // ((60 * 60)*24) 
add_time_to_rental()
{
     integer time_to_add = (secs_per_day*number_of_days_per_payment);
     if(rental_expires == 0) 
     {
          rental_expires = llGetUnixTime() + time_to_add;
     }
     else
     {
          rental_expires = rental_expires + time_to_add;    
     }

}
```

to get when their rental expires
[Unix2DateTime](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Unix2DateTime) is a bit long winded

```
string timeleft()
{
     integer secs_left = rental_expires - llGetUnixTime();
     if(secs_left > 0)
     {
         integer mins_left = llFloor(secs_left / 60);
         integer hours_left = llFloor(mins_left /  60);
         integer days_left = llFloor(hours_left / 24);
         integer weeks_left = llFloor(days_left / 7);
         // correct the values
         if(weeks_left > 0) days_left = days_left - (weeks_left*7);
         if(days_left > 0) hours_left = hours_left - (days_left*24);
         if(hours_left > 0) mins_left = mins_left - (hours_left*60);
         return ""+(string)weeks_left+"weeks, "+(string)days_left+"days, "+(string)hours_left+"hours and "+(string)mins_left+"mins"; 
     }
     else return "Expired"; 
}
```

now you can have a timer event that runs once every 60secs to check if a rental has expired

```
if(llGetUnixTime() > rental_expires) llOwnerSay("Rental has expired");
```

once all of that is in place and working it should be alot easyer for you to add your other code to deal with the 2nd renter.